# Access VBA update table from external ODBC table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, odbc, database-connection

I am trying to update one of my local database table with an external ODBC table in Access VBA.

Part of the update code is shown as below.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim updateQuery As String

updateQuery = "My_Update_Query"

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef
qdf.SQL = updateQuery

qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
```

My code stops running at the qdf.Execute line. I got the error message "Object invalid or no longer set." Error code 3420.

In my update query, I have set my local table field value equal to external ODBC table field value. The external ODBC table is already imported as a link table in my Access.

May I know if I still need to make an explicit connect to the external table here? If so, how can I go about this?

Thanks a lot in advance for the help.

Comment: I always use recordsets for this type of operation if that helps that way you can specify the connection string directly and run transactions on the recordset.

Comment: Do you have a saved query named *My_Update_Query*, and are you trying to execute that query?  If so, does it work without error when you test it in the Access query designer?

Comment: To me this looks possibly like a missing object library reference.  `VBA > Tools > References`.

Comment: @HansUp I got a pop up window asking me to enter parameter value for the linked table. That's why I'm confused if that linked table is really connected when I execute the sql.

Comment: @engineersmnky are you referring to the recordset.edit method? with that it seems I have to update my record one by one instead of executing a simple update query. is there an easy way to achieve that? another reason I did not choose record set is I'm not sure if it can return me the result of the update, being it success or failure.

Comment: What is "My_Update_Query"?  Is that the name of a saved query, a linked table, or something else?

Comment: @HansUp it is a sql query in string, like "Update table1 set table1.a = table2.a where table1.b = table2.b" table 1 is my local table and table 2 is a table linked to odbc

Comment: Test that `UPDATE` statement as a new query in the Access query designer.  Does it work there?

Comment: @HansUp I have finally figured out the error. my ODBC table was not set with a primary key. somehow access would not allow me to update my local table from it if no pk was found. after I explicitly create primary key for this ODBC table, the problem was resolved. the MS error message is not very helpful here. thanks anyway for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

"My_Update_Query" is not a valid SQL statement, which is what `qdf.SQL` would need.  If that's the name of a query you want to run use:

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef

Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("My_Update_Query")
qdf.Execute
```

Or eliminate the whole `QueryDef` stuff and just say:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "My_Update_Query"
```

As long as the ODBC table is linked to your database you shouldn't have to explicitly connect to it each time.

Comment: "My_Update_Query" is not a query object, but a piece of string in my code which containing the update SQL. so I think it cannot be referred to in CurrentDb.QueryDefs("My_Update_Query") directly. I also tried Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(, updateQuery). it also gave me the same "Object invalid or no longer set" error in the qdf.execute statement.

Comment: Can you post the SQL?

Comment: you are right. I do not need to explicitly link the table again, but I have to take care of the primary key when connecting to an ODBC table